# How can I have consistent spacing between my images?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-position, spacing

I am trying to use CSS to obtain consistent spacing between my images that are listed in the skills section of the HTML code. This is the Code:

```css
.skilllogos {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.jslogo {
  padding-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-row">
  <img class="skilllogos" src="images/html.svg" alt="html-icon">
  <img class="skilllogos" src="images/css3.svg" alt="css-icon">
  <img class="skilllogos jslogo" src="images/javascript.svg" alt="javascript-icon">
</div>
```

Adding the padding to the jslogo does seem to solve the problem (that is how i tried to fix it) but it seems like I'm putting on duck tape to fix the issue and there is probably a better way to do this. If I change the height and width of the images then the spacing will become inconsistent again, it's sort of hard coded and I do not want that. If you haven't guessed already, I am very new to web development so your help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please try adding an outline to the image to see if the spacing between images is consistent. I suspect that your svg images may include the space

Comment: dont use a padding but use margin to either the image itself or the class like `.skilllogos{margin: 10px;}`

Comment: add display:inline-block to image

Comment: So I added a border to the image and yes, they are not centered within the box which is the issue. Here's a pic to show you what it looks like ---> https://imgur.com/OlrN6tb

Comment: you should set a `height`  and make the `width: auto`. That will fix your centering issues as well. See my edited answer - sample.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a better solution - smaple. Now your last logo won't have the exrea space on the right. Glad to help ;)

Comment: Use FlexBox CSS with ``justify-content`` on your container: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```css
.skilllogos {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}

.skilllogos:not(:last-of-type) {
    padding-right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-row">
    <img class="skilllogos" src="images/html.svg" alt="html-icon">
    <img class="skilllogos" src="images/css3.svg" alt="css-icon">
    <img class="skilllogos" src="images/javascript.svg" alt="javascript-icon">
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using external links such as jsFiddle, the preferred way on Stack Overflow is to use Stack Snippets that run directly in the question. See [how to use Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Updated my answer with a Stack Snippet

Answer (score 1):

try this

instead of adding **padding-left** add **padding** to all

```css
body{
  background :#111;
  margin:20px auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.skill-row{
  padding:10px;
  background:#fff;
}
.skill-row img{
  padding:14px;
  border:1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-row">
  <img class="skilllogos" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/de4242/fff.svg&text=+HTML+5+" alt="html-icon">
  <img class="skilllogos" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/de4242/fff.svg&text=+CSS+3+" alt="css-icon">
  <img class="skilllogos jslogo" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/de4242/fff.svg&text=+JS+5+" alt="javascript-icon">
</div>
```

Added border to know the space bwteen images by adding js logo only instead add all logo by

```css
.skilllogos {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border:2px solid #111;
  padding:14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-row">
  <img class="skilllogos" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/de4242/fff.png&text=+HTML+5+" alt="html-icon">
  <img class="skilllogos" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/de4242/fff.png&text=+CSS+3+" alt="css-icon">
  <img class="skilllogos jslogo" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/de4242/fff.png&text=+JS+5+" alt="javascript-icon">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and added a border around the images to see if it's spaced correctly however it seems the icons themselves are not centered within their own blocks (the html.svg in particular). Here is an image: https://imgur.com/rnkQga8

Comment: In this case you would need to edit the last svg element. Adding a padding doesn¡t fix the problem. Is just mending it.